# yii 1 sphinx advanced settings

Tags: php, yii, sphinx

I use yii 1 and this [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dgsphinxsearch/)
All works fine, but I need some advanced settings.
Table good has filed good_code. And in this field data stored like

1. 00-00000361
2. 00000006309

So I need when user type 361 (which relate to the first good) or 6309(second good) sphinx find this good.
For now only when I type full code - the good will find.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a string column, you could cast it to a interger and then allow that to be indexed.

Something like

```
sql_query = SELECT * FROM id, title, \ 
  CAST(REPLACE('-','',good_code) AS unsigned) AS good_code \
  FROM ...
```

also adds a REPLACE to rmove the hyphens because that would upset a plain string to number conversion.

(sphinx would turn the integer back to simple string and index it as the raw number)

(May want to do something similar in a query, so if user enters `00000006309` it would still match)